# adding background image in style rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am trying to add background image on my web page, it was working when I was using plane html, but now I am integrating it to my rails application.

I am using this code to embed the image in my rails application

```
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:                                                                                                                                                            
                                    "url(image-url('lines3.png')";                                                                                                                                             
                                      background-repeat: repeat-x;                                                                                                                                             
                                      background-position: center bottom">
```

It is not throwing any exception in logs but not showing the images as well, can suggestions

Comment: Have a look at the rendered html of the div in chrome inspector.  See what the actual image url is, and check whether you can go to that url as a standalone url in another tab.  This should point you to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `"background-image:"url(image-url('lines3.png')";` into `"background-image:"image-url(image-url('lines3.png')";`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

---

Or you can try with: `background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'lines3.png' %>)`

Comment: you mean remove div and style tags

Comment: No, I meant change `url()` to `image-url()`. Maybe this will help.

Comment: none of them worked, I guess the issue is that it is in div and style

Comment: Is your image placed in `app/assets/images` directory?

Comment: yes excatly, the location of image is correct, how I can embed these lines with ruby code,  background-repeat: repeat-x;   background-position: center bottom">

Comment: You shouldn't use inline styling. @pavan answer  should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
<style>

.jumbotron{
  background-image: image-url('lines3.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center bottom;
  }

</style>
```